# Use AWK to compare two files, and perform conditional statements before printing

Tags: awk

I am an AWK-ing novice, and this is, by far, my most complex AWK attempt to date. I have 2 files, one with scan data (FILE1.csv) and another with scan dates (FILE2.csv). I need to compare these 2 files (extracting the dates from FILE2) then with those extracted dates, I need to conditionally check for the correct date, based on which dates are present for the particular target. My current script output yields no results. Any help is greatly appreciated!

FILE1.csv

```
Name,Plugin,Plugin Name,First Discovered,Last Observed,Severity
server1.domain,57608,SMB Signing not required,9/19/2020 20:55,12/3/2022 20:39,Medium
server1.domain,71966,Oracle Java SE Multiple Vulnerabilities (January 2014 CPU),4/22/2021 3:08,12/1/2022 3:14,Critical
server1.domain,94138,Oracle Java SE Multiple Vulnerabilities (October 2016 CPU),4/22/2021 3:08,12/8/2022 3:14,Critical
server2.domain,156032,Apache Log4j Unsupported Version Detection,12/25/2021 3:07,12/8/2022 3:07,Critical
server2.domain,156032,Apache Log4j Unsupported Version Detection,8/31/2022 11:48,11/30/2022 10:16,Critical
server2.domain,156103,Apache Log4j 1.2 JMSAppender Remote Code Execution (CVE-2021-4104),12/25/2021 3:07,12/6/2022 3:07,High
server3.domain,164078,Splunk Enterprise and Universal Forwarder < 9.0 Improper Certificate Validation,10/31/2022 3:13,11/30/2022 10:16,High
server3.domain,166960,Tenable Nessus Agent 10.x < 10.2.1 Multiple Vulnerabilities (TNS-2022-22),11/7/2022 3:14,12/3/2022 3:14,High
server3.domain,168362,VMware Tools 10.x / 11.x / 12.x < 12.1.5 DoS (VMSA-2022-0029),12/5/2022 3:14,12/8/2022 3:14,Low
```

FILE2.csv

```
Name,LAST_VULN_AGENT_SCAN,LAST_VULN_NONCRED_SCAN,LAST_VULN_CRED_SCAN
server1.domain,12/8/2022 3:14,12/3/2022 20:39,
server2.domain,,12/8/2022 3:07,
server3.domain,,12/3/2022 3:14,12/8/2022 3:14
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
Name,Plugin,Plugin Name,First Discovered,Last Observed,Severity
server1.domain,94138,Oracle Java SE Multiple Vulnerabilities (October 2016 CPU),4/22/2021 3:08,12/8/2022 3:14,Critical
server2.domain,156032,Apache Log4j Unsupported Version Detection,12/25/2021 3:07,12/8/2022 3:07,Critical
server3.domain,168362,VMware Tools 10.x / 11.x / 12.x < 12.1.5 DoS (VMSA-2022-0029),12/5/2022 3:14,12/8/2022 3:14,Low
```

**CURRENT SCRIPT**

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{a[$2,$3,$4];next} 
    if (a[$2] && a[$4]) {
        if(a[$2] > a[$4]) {
            if ($5 == a[$2])
            print $0;
        }
        else {
            if ($5 == a[$4])
            print $0;
        }
    }
    else if (a[$2]) {
        if ($5 == a[$2])
        print $0;
    }
    else if (a[$4]) {
        if ($5 == a[$4])
        print $0;
    }
    else {
        if ($5 == a[$3])
        print $0;
    }' FILE1.csv FILE2.csv
```

Edit 1:
Here is my if/then logic to help understand what I'm doing

```
if [ ! -z ${LAST_VULN_AGENT_SCAN} ] && [ ! -z ${LAST_VULN_CRED_SCAN} ]; then
    # AGENT SCAN DATE AND CRED SCAN DATE ARE NOT NULL
    if [ "${AGENT_EPOCH}" -gt "${CRED_EPOCH}" ]; then
        # AGENT SCAN DATE IS MORE RECENT THAN CRED SCAN DATE
        # USE AGENT SCAN DATE TO FILTER COLUMN 5 (Last Observed)
    else
        # CRED SCAN DATE IS MORE RECENT THAN AGENT SCAN DATE
        # USE CRED SCAN DATE TO FILTER COLUMN 5 (Last Observed)
    fi
elif [ ! -z ${LAST_VULN_AGENT_SCAN} ] && [ -z ${LAST_VULN_CRED_SCAN} ]; then
    # AGENT SCAN DATE IS NOT NULL AND CRED SCAN DATE IS NULL
    # USE AGENT SCAN DATE TO FILTER COLUMN 5 (Last Observed)
elif [ -z ${LAST_VULN_AGENT_SCAN} ] && [ ! -z ${LAST_VULN_CRED_SCAN} ]; then
    # CRED SCAN DATE IS NOT NULL AND AGENT SCAN DATE IS NULL
    # USE CRED SCAN DATE TO FILTER COLUMN 5 (Last Observed)
else
    # USE NONCRED SCAN DATE TO FILTER COLUMN 5 (Last Observed)
fi
```

Comment: the `FNR==NR{...}` block processes the first file (`FILE1.csv`); the `END{...}` block processes whatever's in memory *after ALL FILES* have been processed; there is no logic block for processing the second file (`FILE2.csv`); I'm *assuming* your `END{...}` block is actually supposed to process the second file and if that's the case you could start by removing the `END`; having said that ...

Comment: I would suggest you update the question to describe the logic of what you're trying to do; making us try to ascertain your objective by reverse engineering your code doesn't help as we can't tell if your code is 'valid' or not

Comment: in `awk` ... a single `=` is an assignment statement while a double `==` is a test; I'm *assuming* your `if/else-if/else-if/else` block is supposed to be modifying fields (`==` should be `=`) but then you do nothing with the row afterwards ... no `print`, no standalone `1` ... so your script doesn't actually attempt to send anything to stdout

Comment: @markp-fuso I thought in awk the default was to print (so putting print was not necessary). I've added a more verbose output of what my logic is as well

Comment: you either need to explicitly issue a `print/printf` or have a test that evaluates as 'true' with no follow-on `{...}` block

Comment: I don't see anything in the new verbiage that explains how you go from `4/22/2021` in the input to `4/22/21` in the expected output; also, what does `FILTER COLUMN 5` mean ... replace it? keep it? ignore it? something else?  I'd also suggest you trim the datasets down to something more manageable, eg, one line each for `server1` and `server2` that match the criteria, one  line for `server3` that does *not* match the criteria; also add `server4` to `FILE2.csv` and `server5` to `FILE1.csv` and show us how these should (not) show up in the expacted output

Comment: also, in the new verbiage you reference `LAST_VULN_AGENT_SCAN` but for all lines in `FILE2.csv` this field is empty; if the existence, or non-existence, of this field has an effect on processing then also consider modifying `FILE2.csv` to show such differences

Comment: @markp-fuso I updated FILE1.csv, FILE2 will always have a corresponding value in FILE1 (so adding a server4 or server5 is not needed) I hope I'm explaining that correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues with OP's current code:

- while processing the 1st file 3 columns are used as the index for the `a[]` array (`a[$2,$3,$4]`) but ...
- during processing of the 2nd file only 1 column is ever used for referencing the `a[]` array; net result is that none of the tests will evaluate as 'true'
- I'm assuming that all relationships between `FILE1.csv` and `FILE2.csv` are based on a common `Name` (eg, `server1.domain`) so there needs to be some sort of comparison of `$1` between the two files; more specifically, array indices should probably be based on `$1`
- during processing of the 2nd file we have to first test to see if an array entry exists before we try referencing it otherwise ... if the array doesn't exist we'll actually create a new array entry when trying to reference it; likely not an issue with this particular process but better to understand, and fix, this issue now than to continue with this coding style and end up with unexpected results with later `awk` scripts

Additional items we need to address:

- since we'll be dealing with 3 different dates we'll look at using a separate array for managing the dates; to keep with OP's column references we'll call them `dt2[]` (re `$2`), `dt3[]` (re: `$3`) and `dt4[]` (re: `$4`)
- comparing 2 dates is easier if we convert to epoch and them compare the epoch values; if `$2` > `$4` we'll create an entry in the `greater[]` array

Pulling all of this together into our `awk` script:

```
awk '
BEGIN   { FS=OFS="," }
FNR==NR { if (FNR==1)
             next

          if ($2) dt2[$1]=$2
          if ($3) dt3[$1]=$3
          if ($4) dt4[$1]=$4

          if ($2 && $4) {
             split($2,a,"[ /:]")
             epoch2=mktime(a[3] " " a[1] " " a[2] " " a[4] " " a[5] " 0")

             split($4,a,"[ /:]")
             epoch4=mktime(a[3] " " a[1] " " a[2] " " a[4] " " a[5] " 0")

             if (epoch2 > epoch4)
                greater[$1]
          }
          next
        }
FNR==1  { printme=1 }                                  # set print flag
FNR>1   { printme=0                                    # clear print flag

          if ($1 in dt2 && $1 in dt4) {
              if ($1 in greater) {
                 if ($5 == dt2[$1])
                    printme=1
              }
              else if ($5 == dt4[$1]) {
                 printme=1
              }
           }
           else if ($1 in dt2) {
              if ($5 == dt2[$1])
                 printme=1
           }
           else if ($1 in dt4) {
              if ($5 == dt4[$1])
                 printme=1
           }
           else if ($1 in dt3) {
              if ($5 == dt3[$1])
                 printme=1
           }
        }
printme                                                # if print flag == 1 then print current line to stdout
' FILE2.csv FILE1.csv
```

This generates:

```
Name,Plugin,Plugin Name,First Discovered,Last Observed,Severity
server1.domain,94138,Oracle Java SE Multiple Vulnerabilities (October 2016 CPU),4/22/2021 3:08,12/8/2022 3:14,Critical
server2.domain,156032,Apache Log4j Unsupported Version Detection,12/25/2021 3:07,12/8/2022 3:07,Critical
server3.domain,168362,VMware Tools 10.x / 11.x / 12.x < 12.1.5 DoS (VMSA-2022-0029),12/5/2022 3:14,12/8/2022 3:14,Low
```

Comment: Thanks! I am testing this now!

Comment: It appears my awk doesn't have mktime, its throwing an error
awk: calling undefined function mktime
my awk version is:
awk version 20021213

Comment: Could I rewrite the date as YYYYmmddHHMMSS? This would then allow for comparison

Comment: I changed it, and it is working epoch2="a[3]a[1]a[2]a[4]a[5]" epoch4="a[3]a[1]a[2]a[4]a[5]", also I corrected your 2nd split, both splits were using $2, when the 2nd split should be using $3

Comment: re: 2nd `split()` ... cut-n-paste oops; should be `$4` (I've updated the answer)

Comment: @27560  re: `mktime()` issue ... yeah, that could be the case if you're not running `GNU awk` or `mawk`; and, sure, `YYYYmmddHHMMSS` works, too :-)

Comment: re: 2nd split() also need to update the if statement as well to if ($2 && $4)